# MapReduce function to find intersection of sets

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

**What I want:**

to design MapReduce function which has

Input:

key1 \t A1 \t B1

key2 \t A2 \t B2

key3 \t A3 \t B3

....

key30 \t A30 \t B30

Desired output:

"min" \t intersect(A1,A2,A3...)

"max" \t intersect(B1,B2,B3,...)

where A1,A2,A3,..B1,B2,B3 are sets of sets.

**What I did**:

I design Mapper and Reducer as below.

Mapper:

```
 public static class MapAPP extends Mapper<Text, Text, Text, Text>{     

    public static int j=0,k=0;
    public static List<String> min_pre = new ArrayList<>();
    public static List<String> min_current = new ArrayList<>();
    public static Set<String> min_p1 = new HashSet<>();
    public static Set<String> min_c1 = new HashSet<>();
    public static List<String> min_result = new ArrayList<>(); 
    public static Boolean no_exist_min=false;

    public static List<String> max_pre = new ArrayList<>();
    public static List<String> max_current = new ArrayList<>();
    public static Set<String> max_p1 = new HashSet<>();
    public static Set<String> max_c1 = new HashSet<>();
    public static List<String> max_result = new ArrayList<>(); 
    public static Boolean no_exist_max=false;

    public void map(Text key, Text value, Context con) throws IOException, InterruptedException
    {
        String[] v=value.toString().split("\t");
        // aggregate min
        if (no_exist_min==false){
            if (j==0){
                    min_pre= Arrays.asList(v[0].toString().trim().split("\\|"));
                    j=1;
                 }else{
                    min_current= Arrays.asList(v[0].toString().trim().split("\\|")); 
                    for (String p: min_pre){                   
                       min_p1 = new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList(p.split(",")));
                       for (String c: min_current){
                           min_c1 = new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList(c.split(",")));
                           min_c1.retainAll(min_p1);
                           if (!min_c1.isEmpty()){
                               Joiner m_comma = Joiner.on(",").skipNulls();
                               String buff = m_comma.join(min_c1);
                               if (!min_result.contains(buff))
                                    min_result.add(buff);
                           }                       
                       }                   
                    }
                    if (min_result.isEmpty()){
                        no_exist_min=true;          
                    } else {                    
                        min_pre=new ArrayList(min_result);
                        min_result.clear();                       
                    }
            }                   
        }

        //aggregate max
        if (no_exist_max==false){
            if (k==0){
                    max_pre= Arrays.asList(v[1].toString().trim().split("\\|"));
                    k=1;
                 }else{
                    max_current= Arrays.asList(v[1].toString().trim().split("\\|")); 
                    for (String p: max_pre){                   
                       max_p1 = new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList(p.split(",")));
                       for (String c: max_current){
                           max_c1 = new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList(c.split(",")));
                           max_c1.retainAll(max_p1);
                           if (!max_c1.isEmpty()){
                               Joiner m_comma = Joiner.on(",").skipNulls();
                               String buff = m_comma.join(max_c1);
                               if (!max_result.contains(buff))
                                    max_result.add(buff);
                           }                       
                       }                   
                    }
                    if (max_result.isEmpty()){
                        no_exist_max=true;          
                    } else {                    
                        max_pre=new ArrayList(max_result);
                        max_result.clear();                       
                    }
            }                   
        }

    }

    protected void cleanup(Context con) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        Joiner m_pipe = Joiner.on("|").skipNulls();
        if (no_exist_min==true){
            con.write(new Text("min"), new Text("no_exist"));
        }else {               
            String min_str = m_pipe.join(min_pre);
            con.write(new Text("min"), new Text(min_str)); 

        }

        if (no_exist_max==true){
            con.write(new Text("max"), new Text("no_exist"));
        }else {
            String max_str = m_pipe.join(max_pre);                
            con.write(new Text("max"), new Text(max_str));                
        }            
        min_p1.clear();
        min_c1.clear();
        min_result.clear();

        max_p1.clear();
        max_c1.clear();
        max_result.clear();
    }
}
```

Reducer:

```
public static class ReduceAPP extends Reducer<Text, Text, Text, Text>
{
    public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<Text> values, Context con) throws IOException, InterruptedException
    {
        List<String> pre = new ArrayList<>();
        List<String> current = new ArrayList<>();
        Set<String> p1 = new HashSet<>();
        Set<String> c1 = new HashSet<>();
        List<String> result = new ArrayList<>();
        Joiner comma = Joiner.on(",").skipNulls(); 
        Joiner pipe = Joiner.on("|").skipNulls(); 
        Boolean no_exist=false;
        String preStr="";
        int i=0;
        // aggregate
        for(Text value: values){
             if (value.toString().trim()=="no_exist"){
                 no_exist=true;
                 break;
                }
             if (i==0){
                    pre= Arrays.asList(value.toString().trim().split("\\|"));
                    i=1;
             }else{
                    current= Arrays.asList(value.toString().trim().split("\\|")); 
                    for (String p: pre){                   
                       p1 = new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList(p.split(",")));
                       for (String c: current){
                           c1 = new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList(c.split(",")));
                           c1.retainAll(p1);
                           if (!c1.isEmpty()){
                               String buff = comma.join(c1);
                               if (!result.contains(buff))
                                    result.add(buff);
                           }                       
                       }                   
                    }
                    if (result.isEmpty()){
                        no_exist=true;
                        break;
                    }
                    pre=new ArrayList(result);
                    result.clear();                       
             }                   

        }
        if (no_exist==true){
            con.write(key, new Text("no_exist"));
        }
        else{
            preStr = pipe.join(pre);
            con.write(key, new Text(preStr)); 
        }
        System.out.println("Reducefinished: key="+key.toString()+", value= "+preStr);
    }
    public static <T> Set<T> union(Set<T> setA, Set<T> setB) {
        Set<T> tmp = new TreeSet<T>(setA);
        tmp.addAll(setB);
        return tmp;
    }
}
```

The codes belows looks complicate, but the idea is very simple. To calculate intersection(A1,A2,A3), I first calculate A12=intersection(A1,A2), then calculate A13=intersect(A12,A3), and so on, until the end. I do the same to intersect(B1,B2,B3). In fact, my Mapper and Reduce code is almost the same. The difference is where I output: in cleanup function of each mapper while in reduce function of my Reducer.

For you to easily imagine:

My mapper output:

Mapper1:

min \t A16=intersect(A1,A2,..A6)

max \t B16=intersect(B1,B2,..B6)

Mapper2:

min \t A715=intersect(A7,A8,..A15)

max \t B715=intersect(B7,B8,..B15)

Mapper3:

min \t A1622=intersect(A16,A17,..A22)

max \t B1622=intersect(B16,B17,..B22)

Mapper4:

min \t A2330=intersect(A23,A24,..A30)

max \t B2330=intersect(B23,B24,..B30)

My reducer output:

Reducer1: min \t A130=intersect(A16,A715,A1622,A2330)

Reducer2: max \t B130=intersect(B16,B715,B1622,B2330)

**Problem**

Reducer1 is calculated pretty easily due to fewer number of sets in A. 
But because size of B >> size of A, so Reducer2 takes a lot of time and sometimes I got heap overflow error. What can I do to make my Reducer2 process faster?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Please reformat your question properly, remove unwanted '\t'

Comment: I think adding \t makes my question clearer? Dont you think so?